# What is the best way to pass information from app.js?

Tags: node.js

In the code below, what is best way to pass information from app.js to choices.js ?
Currently, I put them all in a variable called answer.
Is that the best way to do it ?
Thank you.

These are the code in app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var sql = require('msnodesqlv8');
:
var choicesTerm = [];
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   console.log(`${req.method} request for '${req.url}' -      
   ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);
next();
});

var connStr = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};....";
sql.open(connStr, function (err, conn) {        
    var pm = conn.procedureMgr();
    pm.callproc('mySP',sessionID, function (err, results) {
    :
        pm.callproc('mySp2', function (err, results) {
        :            
        if (results.length) 
        {
            var row = results[0];
            var Answers = [];
            Answers = row.Answers.split("|");
            for (var i = 0, len = Answers.length; i < len; i++) {
                var answer = {value: Answers[i], description: Answers[i], question: row.text, detail: row.detail};  //--> pass information to choices.js
                choicesTerm[i] = answer;
            }
         }
      })
   });
 });

 app.use(express.static("./public"));
 app.use(cors());
 app.get("/choices-api", function(req, res) {
    res.json(choicesTerm);
 });
```

These are the code in choices.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON('/choices-api', printTerms);
 });

function printTerms(terms) {
   var question = terms[0].question;  //--> This is passed from app.js
    var detail = terms[0].detail;   //--> This is passed from app.js
 }
```

Comment: general techniques for sharing ,   cache api, service-worker, regular worker, blob with object URL, and or file-system

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you for your reply. Did you mean that another way to pass information to choices.js is thru  cache api, service-worker, regular worker, blob with object URL, and or file-system ?

Comment: yes    thats correct